# What is the reason/benefit for writing short circuit conditional?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

I was searching a lot about short circuit, but I have a big doubt with this code.

```
const getClient = (userInfoContext) => {
  const context = userInfoContext && userInfoContext.get()
  const payload = context && context.payload && context.payload['www.payload.com']
  return payload && payload.clientId
}
```

I want to know what is the benefit of write the code like that instead of:

```
  const getClient = (userInfoContext) => {
  const context = userInfoContext.get()
  const payload = context.payload['www.payload.com']
  return payload.clientId
}
```

Comment: To prevent `Cannot read property "payload" of undefined`. It's how we used to do `context?.payload?.['www.payload.com']` before `?.` was a thing.